# Getting the right access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-access-token

I'd like my application could read the posts from a group.

To do it, I got the access token in the following url:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=404425692946289%2Ffeed

and I call que following url:

https://graph.facebook.com/404425692946289/feed?access_token=debug_token_generated_from_above_url

And it works like a charm.

But I can't get any results when I call the url above with the token that was generated using my application id and secret:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=myid&client_secret=mysecret&grant_type=client_credentials <--- The token generated by this url does not work! =(

I am receiving the following data:

{
   "data": [

]
}

I supposedly have the read_stream extended permission configured on my application.

Answer (score 2):

One way to check for your self what permissions the token in the API explorer has, is to call `/me/permissions`

In addition `grant_type=client_credentials` is for app tokens. You need a user token most likely. Please review the documentation where you got that information from.